# Exclude "http" or "http://www." from angularjs form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I search how to exclude

> http

and with the 'www' from a textarea :

```
            <div id="textareaPart">
                <label for="textarea" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                    Your message
                    <span class="myForm_error" ng-show="myFormZR.textarea.$error.required">(champ needed)</span>
                    <span class="myForm_textarea" ng-show="myFormZR.textarea.$dirty"> - characters : {{0 + myForm.textarea.length}} / 500</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="textarea" rows="3" required="required" placeholder="500 characters max..." maxlength="500" ng-model="myForm.textarea"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
```

it's ng-pattern ? i know how to allow with a regexp but how to exclude ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
ng-pattern="/^((?!www|http[s]{0,1}:\/\/www).)*$/";
```

This will allow **every value except** if it contains:

- `www`
- `http://www`
- `https://www`

Comment: thanks :) I want to put in a var , when i do :   var textareaRegex = "/^((?!www|http[s]{0,1}:\/\/www).)*$/";   it's doesn't work, what is the correct syntax

Comment: The correct syntax is: `var textareaRegex = /^((?!www|http[s]{0,1}:\/\/www).)*$/;` without the quotes (`"`). You are getting everything error because your syntax is wrong.